# Dynamically create 2d array ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to create the following 2d array dynamically:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [4, 2]]
```

Eg.

```
(1..4).to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
(1..2).to_a
#=> [1, 2]
```

Combine this somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Array#product](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array%3Aproduct) is the method you're looking for:

```
(1..4).to_a.product (1..2).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like a homework question. It would be nice to get context around what you're trying to do. You'll want to spend some time researching the different loops/iterators that ruby provides you. Here is a method that will return the array you're looking for by using one of ruby's iterator methods `upto`.

```
def generate_array
  arr = []

  1.upto(4) do |y|
    1.upto(2) do |x|
      arr << [y, x]
    end
  end

  arr
end
```